# How to take the input value of an html Input on the onBlur event from a controller using VB.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have this html input in the `.ascx` file:

```
<input runat="server" id="filterTitle" name="filterTitle" type="text"/>
```

In the `.ascx.vb` file I need to take the value of the above input when the user leaves the text box, the below code is working fine, it takes the input's value on the first load of the file:

```
Partial Class Controls_View_News
    Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl
    Protected Overrides Sub OnInit(e As EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnInit(e)
        Dim VALUE As String
        VALUE = filterTitle.Value
```

I need to let `VALUE` to be equal the input's value whenever use types in the text box and leaves it.

Comment: @mplungjan thought it could be done with databinding? it is the first time for me working on a VB.NET project. but I believe it can be done with `dataBinding`?

Comment: [So have a look](https://www.google.com/search?q=databinding+asp+input+field+site:stackoverflow.com)